# C#: How to make a pure compiler barrier? (equivalent to gcc asm volatile)

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, x86, memory-barriers

C#: (on x86) How to make a pure compiler barrier, *without* any asm instructions to give any extra run-time ordering? (Equivalent to gcc `asm volatile("" ::: "memory")` or msvc `_ReadWriteBarrier`)

Like C++ `atomic_signal_fence()`, not `atomic_thread_fence()`.

On x86 specifically, blocking compile-time reordering without blocking run-time reordering is like C++ `atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel)` but not `seq_cst`. (https://godbolt.org/z/19h7K1fP3).  On most other ISAs, it would give no run-time ordering guarantees except wrt. signal or exception handlers within the same thread.

https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/

Comment: Is [`Thread.MemoryBarrier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier?view=net-6.0) not what you need?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The docs for that talks about blocking hardware (run-time) reordering.  (But strangely talks about *executing* instructions, not talking about when stores actually become globally visible sometime after they execute, when the store buffer drains). It probably needs to be x86 `mfence` or `lock add dword [rsp], 0` or equivalent.  This question is asking for *just* blocking compile-time reordering, like C++ `atomic_signal_fence()` (not `thread_fence`) or like an *empty* inline asm statement with a memory clobber: `asm( "" ::: "memory" )`

Comment: If all you want to block is compiler instruction rearranging, you can call an external (P/Invoke) function. Though I doubt that your problem is anything other than a self-created one, and you could work around it by changing whatever XY problem you actually have.

Comment: [`System.Threading.Barrier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.barrier?view=net-6.0) appears to be the best answer to the question, but it's a JIT and is allowed to do whatever it wants within the memory model of the language. C# has very strong compile time reordering guarantees last I checked. So I'm not sure this is even technically an issue?

Comment: @Mgetz Threading.Barrier() is irrelevant. This is pattern of task synchronization.

Comment: @user2771324: compiler barrier still doesn't prevent the CPU from reordering the instructions, so if you are doing task synchronization on multiple cores, use actual built in [C# synchronization primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives). In many cases, the lightest way to sync is using the `Interlocked` class.

Comment: @Groo I know what I am doing, and that is why I explicitly ask for compiler barrier and gives C example. On the other side, I am not sure if Interlocked have a partial or full compiler barrier -- it is not mentioned in document (while Volatile.Read mentions barrier, but by common sense, Volatile compiler barrier is not necessarily a full compiler barrier).